# MySQL - select post ID only if there is no winner set in the same table, but different row. Sample code included

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress table wp_postmeta and what I want is a list of all posts where `sttf_split_test_status = 'active'` but it CAN NOT have another meta row with the same post_id and a meta_key of `stti_winner` set. My below code returns empty, but there should be a result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'sttf_split_test_status' 
  AND meta_value = 'active' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT post_id 
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    WHERE post_id = post_id 
    AND meta_key = 'stti_winner'
  )
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: @Alex converting from 2-space to an inconsistent mix of 4-space and 5-space is not a readability improvement; I have reverted your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT yes.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta AS yes
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS no 
  ON yes.post_id=no.post_id
  AND no.meta_key='stti_winner'
WHERE yes.meta_key = 'sttf_split_test_status' 
AND yes.meta_value = 'active' 
AND no.post_id IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 25
;
```

Explanation: To every fitting record we try to join the corresponding 'stti_winner'. Only if that fails (fields of `LEFT JOIN` stay `NULL`), we accept the record.

Comment: Bingo. And thanks for the explanation, that's 100x better than just an answer.